# ASPNET. - Reponse code 500 when doing Ajax call produces

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have write small application base aspnet with ajax
and i have function ajax look like that

//ajax code

```
function currentAccountApiToken(userId){
    data = JSON.stringify({
        "accountID": userId
    })
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: '/Configurate/controller.aspx/getListApiKey',
        data:data,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result){
            var data = JSON.parse(result.d);
            console.log(data.result);

            var isExec1 = (data.result[0].isExecute) == 1 ? true : false;
            console.log(isExec1);
            $('label#apiTokenOne').empty().append(data.result[0].apiToken)
            toggleswitch(isExec1,'');
            //parse data to element            
            $('label#apiTokenTwo').empty().append(data.result[1].apiToken)
            var isExec2 = (data.result[1].isExecute) == 1 ? true : false;

        },
        error: (error) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
```

// c# code

//get list profile

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string get_list_profiles_user(string _account_id)
    {
        var temp = new Entity.DBEntity.tblProfileUser();
        temp._account_id = _account_id;
        string _query_string = temp.get_profile_name();
        List<Entity.DBEntity.tblProfileUser> _list_profiles = Configurate.sqlBuilder.get_list_profiles(_query_string, Configurate.DBConnection._mysqlcon);
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            _list_profiles
        });
    }
```

however, when i running code, the return http code 500 with error

> jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 POST
>   http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:88/Configurate/controller.aspx/get_list_profiles_user
>   profile.js:290 {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"Message\":\"There
>   was an error processing the
>   request.\",\"StackTrace\":\"\",\"ExceptionType\":\"\"}","responseJSON":{"Message":"There
>   was an error processing the
>   request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""},"status":500,"statusText":"Internal
>   Server Error"}

so please help me, 
thanks !

Comment: A 500 error indicates a problem in your c# code.  Use your debugger and find out what the issue is.

Comment: You have code in your question.  Don't format it as quotes.  Keep it readable.

Comment: Lol I wonder how many exceptions in code like this are `NullReferenceException`'s ? My guess that it is 7-8 out of 10

Comment: wrap your controller method in a try.. catch(Exception ex), put a breakpoint inside the catch block and watch ex. You will now what is wrong then

Comment: @amy Thank your response, i have try but still issue. when i debug with url
http://localhost:51110/dashboard/listprofile.aspx. then working well
however, when i trying with production enviroment with real ip
looklike: http://18.18.14.124:88//dashboard/listprofile.aspx then have issue

Comment: @cid i dont think so, because, i using c# template code as above for other function then running well

Comment: @cid that's optional. That line is fine as is.

Comment: @LittleBoy Then add some exception handling and log the error.

Comment: what's the actual error? Put in a try...catch with logging / returning the full error message, or look at event viewer on the server, or turn on errors for remote pages. Difficult to know, but high probability you have a null reference in there

Comment: the trouble that, when running mode debug then not show any issue, just issue when lunch product enviroment

Comment: If it's only happening in prod, error logging could help. Maybe the underlying database query is failing on one environment versus the other

Comment: @LittleBoy Do you know what a "log file" is?

Comment: @Jonathan yes, only prod enviroment, then to hard...

Comment: @Amy i will try tracer log to debug

Comment: @amy, after trace log, just see follow access resource...

Comment: I would have simply returned a "Hello World" string to test the ajax call to see if it is on the correct endpoint. Then would have gone towards adding my code.